# Is there any package, API or etc. which can return boolean if an iCal Vevent is at the moment Active?

Tags: java, icalendar

So i’ve been searching the web & stackoverflow for this question for more than 2 days, but i wasn’t able to find anything.

I’ll clarify the question again. Each *.iCal file has “vevents” and many other components like “summary”, “datestart”.

I want to search an *.iCal file whether an “vevent” with an particular summary, for example, “summary=testevent” is at this current time active. **BUT I want to do so with an library or package.**

By currently active I mean like that the event is happening right now. If you look at this example event, it currently is active:
[image]

The reason I ask is because there are many rules you can apply when setting up an calendar event. Like, every second tuesday, every fifth month on the 5th and etc.
I don’t want to hear how you can program it, as I am trying to do so for over 2 weeks. It is more complicated than it looks. Have a look at all the special rules an event can have: [image]

Is there any Package, library, etc. , you are aware of which can do so?

Comment: Almost any ics parser should iterate out the recurrences then you just have to check for an instance if start < now and end > now.  https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+ics+parser

Comment: that's totally not how it works... there are special rules example event is every monday and tuestay. Now and End is example 10.12.2020 2pm to 6pm, o clock and RRULE;BYDAY=MO,TU,,, the Now and End date is always the same and in the past after it occurs once,, but the event has still to be active every monday and tuestay from 2pm to 6pm, o clock! and there are like 50 such combinations

Comment: That totally is how 'it' works (of course we may not be talking about the same 'it' lol).  The RRULE no matter how complex it is has to be parsed, as well as any VEVENTS with a RECURRENCE-ID that matches the UID of the main VEVENT.  All related VEVENTS determine the valid set of instances generated within the timeframe being looked at.

Comment: TO be clear while I can imagine logically how one could maybe programmaticaly search a ical file and check DTSTART's,  DTENDSs OR DURATIONS and UNTILS (if they exist) and then check for any modifying VEVENTS with RECURRENCE-IDS, I don't know of a library that would offer you a function to determine within a file what is an 'active' event without parsing the file.   As you correctly point out recurring events can be complex so why rewrite all the logic that deals with all the possibilities if parsers already do that ?

Comment: You got the Question wrong. I am allready parsing them with an own written i'll call it "script". Parsing and iterating throug each VEVENT isn't the problem. The problem is determining whether VEVENT with SUMMARY:EXAMPLE is currently ACTIVE. By active i mean the VEVENT is currently happening.

I have allready parsed all RRULES and seperated them. BYMONTH, BYMONTHDAY, BYDAY, SETPOS and etc.

I have all the data but it's very complex to determine with this data whether VEVENTS are currentl happening/active.

Comment: Yeah the Parser is not the problem, I have all the data the problem is only determining whether event is currently active or not and the parsers I have looked at don't have that "function" built in.

Comment: OK, to be clear I'm assuming a good parser library also has an RRULE iterator because yes that is where things get gnarly, particularly when there is also possibly timezones and daylight saving to consider. or if floating events etc, not to mention all the weird BYxxxx rules.  A quick google using keywords like "java iterate RRULE" shows some but I cannot recommend any.  I spent way too long writing my own many years ago but while stable, covers pretty much all,  it's dedicated to its purpose and also php not java.